# Do I need a UK airside transit visa, if I already have a UK visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen and I do not qualify for DATV concession. Going for a trip to UK and Europe, I am having Multiple entry valid Visitor visa for UK. While on my way back from Paris I will be transiting in Heathrow airport. Do I need to take a airside transit visa even though I have a multiple entry valid UK visitor visa?

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need additional visa. From [UK Border Agency](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/sitecontent/documents/policyandlaw/modernised/visiting/general-visitor.pdf?view=Binary):

> **Multi-entry visas**:
>   Visas are valid for an unlimited number of journeys within the
>   validity period of the visa.
>
> People holding visit visas can only remain in the UK for a maximum of six months on any one visit, or
>   until the visa expires if less than six months. This restriction is
>   indicated on the visa by the entry ‘180’ days after the ‘Duration of
>   stay’ section.
>
> Holders of long term visit visas must still meet the
>   requirements of the Immigration Rules each time they enter the UK.
>   They must not be using the route to live in the UK for extended
>   periods. If it is apparent this is the case Border Force officers must
>   refuse entry to the UK.

So you can see there is no restriction for minimum period of stay and you can use your visa for a transit.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I believe everybody agrees with this reply.

Comment: The citation given here is out-of-date and has been archived by the government.  Check your link.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Dirty-flow's answer, The general visitor visa is mandated for a land side transit which is greater than 48 hours and can be used for lesser than 48 hours landside or airside transits as well.

Additionally for reference the *don'ts* on the [UK Gov website](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa) do not prohibit the use of the visa for such purpose either.