# Transit visa to UK required if I already have valid business visa for UK

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I will be travelling to UK on business visa in August for a week. But in september I have plans to transit through UK to Jamaica. I have booked a flight which will be landing in London heathrow airport and then get on another plane from Gatwick airport within 24 hours.

Question - Do I need to apply for transit visa as well or I can transit on my Business visa?

Comment: For a start - what's the validity on your business visa?

Comment: Valid till six months from now

Comment: Multiple entries or single entry??

Comment: multiple entries

Comment: I think you'll be fine. What kind of business visa are you on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to obtain a UK transit visa if you already hold a more senior visa of any type.  The primary legislation for this situation is in Section 33 of the [Immigration Act 1971](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/77/pdfs/ukpga_19710077_en.pdf), which is referenced in [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423477/20150424_mmigration_rules_app_v_final_v2.pdf) of the current rules...

> visit visa means an entry clearance for the purpose of a visit under
>   section 33 of the Immigration Act 1971. It is normally a vignette in
>   the holder’s passport. It includes entry clearances for visitors that
>   were issued under paragraphs 40-56, 56D-56J, 56N-56Z, 75A-75M of these
>   Rules and Appendix V

Based upon what you wrote, you have a visitor visa which will be in force during your transit.  By default, these visas are multiple entry with a term of 6 months.  During that period you can engage in any of the "[permitted activities](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview)", which includes transit.

Related question:  [Do I need a transit visa if I already have a UK Business visit visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49345/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-if-i-already-have-a-uk-business-visit-visa)

See also:  [Do I need a UK airside transit visa, if I already have a UK visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18140/do-i-need-a-uk-airside-transit-visa-if-i-already-have-a-uk-visitor-visa)