# I have a UK visitor visa starting on 30 Oct; will I need a DATV for an itinerary on 12 Sep?

Tags: visas, uk, lhr, datv

I am traveling on a BA flight from Amsterdam - Mumbai via London (LHR). I have a visitor visa for the UK starting one month after my current travel.

Will I require a Direct Airside Transit Visa (DATV)?

Also, would my visitor visa, which is yet to start, be cancelled?

Comment: Well, yes, you need a transit visa if your transit is outside the validity dates  of your visit visa.  See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: If your transit is inside the validity dates of your visa, see Related:  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50511/transit-visa-to-uk-required-if-i-already-have-valid-business-visa-for-uk/50512#50512

Comment: Do [any of the DATV exemptions for Indian citizens](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no) apply to you on this earlier trip?

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa